# S.redirectTo leads always to a blank screen

Tags: scala, lift

I am now playing a little bit with lift (2.1), and all the features in LiftRules work as intended.
But I haven't been able to use S.redirectTo at all.  I always ends with a blank screen, no matter what.
No error messages at all!

As an example, I have the following form:

```
...
  <lift:logIn.logInForm form="post">
    <p><login:name /></p>
    <p><login:password /></p>
    <p><login:submit /></p>
  </lift:logIn.logInForm>
  ...
```

And the code is:

```
object LogIn extends helper.LogHelper {

    ...
    def logInForm(in: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
      var name = ""
      var password = ""

          def login() = {
          logger.info("name: " + name)
          logger.info("password: " + password)
          if (name == "test1") S.redirectTo("/example")
          if (name == "test2") S.redirectTo("/example.html")
          if (name == "test3") S.redirectTo("example.html")
          S.redirectTo("/")
          }

    bind("login", in,
      "name" ->     SHtml.text(name, name = _),
      "password" -> SHtml.password(password, password = _),
      "submit" ->   SHtml.submit("Login", login))
    }
  }
```

The method 'login' is invoked, I can check that in the log information.  But as I said, no matter which name I enter, I always end with a blank screen, although 'example.html' is available when being accessed directly in the browser.
How should I invoke S.redirectoTo in order to navigate to 'examples.html'? Also, why don't I receive an error message (I am logging at a debug level)?

I think all the configuration in Boot is correct, since all LitRules examples (statelessRewrite, dispatch, viewDispatch, snippets) work fine.

---

Edited:

/example was not in the SiteMap.
I have added /example and /index like that:

```
def boot {
  ...
  val index = Menu(Loc("index", new Link(List("index"), false), "index"))
  val example = Menu(Loc("example", new Link(List("example"), false), "example"))
  LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(index, example))
  ...    
}
```

Still nothing happens  :-(

Any idea?

Comment: Have you added the `example.html` page to your `SiteMap`?

Comment: 2.8.0 will be the version of Scala you're using, not the version of Lift, for which 2.2 is the latest release.  It would help to know which Lift version you're *really* using!

Comment: are you sure, that you don't have a typo there? You have example in code, but then in text, you refer to example`s`.

Comment: Do I need to add example.html to SiteMap when using redirectTo?  How do I do it?  I am not using SiteMap at all...

Comment: I corrected my typo (example.html) & the lift version  (2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Anything you `redirectTo` needs to be in SiteMap.

Comment: I added /index and /example to the SiteMap (see my changes), but it still does not work...